# Compound COUNTIFS with LEFT used in an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I'm trying to count instances of differing occurrences that must meet a string criteria, then also filter by timespan against a date time string in one block. I need to leave the worksheet intact and simply run the function in a header worksheet.
This is my generic formula which simply returns a '0' when run as an array function:

```
=COUNTIFS('SHEET'!$C$2:$C$100,$B5,'SHEET'!$K$2:$K$100,$E$3-LEFT('SHEET'!$K$2:$K$100,12)<8)
```

> Column C here is checked against a string in B5.
> "SHEET" Column K has the date_time string with the date being the first 12 chars (Hence LEFT() function)
> The date of the report is input in E5 to calculate timespan against Column K and check that it is within one week (<8).

Through various attempts, I have seen the formula have the typical 'spill' effect. The simple formula checking against the text string works. However, my complication comes from trying to use the compound formula altogether.

I've attempted the same calculation to no avail using the following as an array also:

```
=SUM(IF(AND('SHEET'!$C$2:$C$100=$B$5,$E$3-LEFT('SHEET'!$K2:$K100,12)<8),1,))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('SHEET'!$C$2:$C$100=$B5)*($E$3-LEFT('SHEET'!$K$2:$K$100,12)<8))
```

This will create two arrays of TRUE/FALSE and by MULTIPLYING them together we turn TRUE into 1 and FALSE into 0.  If either is FALSE the result for the row is  0 if BOTH are TRUE then we get 1 for the row.

It then SUMS the resulting array of 1s and 0s.

BTW your SUM formula did not work because AND() does not work with array formula.

It could be rewritten as:

```
=SUM(IF(('SHEET'!$C$2:$C$100=$B5)*($E$3-LEFT('SHEET'!$K$2:$K$100,12)<8),1,))
```

And depending on version may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.